# AsyncTask. Как поймать onPostExecute в вызывающем классе

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Всем привет. Имею класс вызывающий загрузку изображений с сервера в память устройства.
Вызывающий класс вызывает класс загрузчика в цикле.
Хочу повесить дополнительное условие для каждой итерации если в ответ onPostExecute -> true, то есть нужно обрабатывать как то ошибки для до следующего вызова.
Вот пример кода.
**Вызывающий класс :**

```
`for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; i++)
                        switch (i){
                            case 0:
                                new Download(getActivity(),"https://mydomain.com/","0002-2021-08-10.jpg","mBipmapsImage1");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                new Download(getActivity(),"https://mydomain.com/","0027-2021-08-11.jpg","mBipmapsImage2");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                new Download(getActivity(),"https://mydomain.com/","0104-2021-08-10.jpg","mBipmapsImage3");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                new Download(getActivity(),"https://mydomain.com/","0356-2021-08-12.jpg","mBipmapsImage4");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                new Download(getActivity(),"https://mydomain.com/","0409-2021-08-04.jpg","mBipmapsImage5");
                                break;
                        }`
```

**Класс с AsyncTask :**

```
public Download (Context context, String mUrl, String mImageName,String mfile_name){
        this._context = context;
        sUrl = mUrl;
        sImageName = mImageName;
        file_name = mfile_name;
        requestStoragePermission();
    }  
public class ShareTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        URL myFileUrl;
        Bitmap bmImg = null;
        File file;

        public ShareTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        //------------------------------------------Диалог --------------------------------------//
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            pDialog.setMessage(_context.getString(R.string.loading_msg));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        //----------------------------------------- HttpURLConnection  --------------------------------------//
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
                String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + _context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "/");
                dir.mkdirs();
                String fileName = idStr;
                file = new File(dir, file_name);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 99, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog != null)
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
```

Comment: 1) а в чем собственно вопрос? 2) почему просто не использовать библиотеку для загрузки картинок?

Comment: @Pentiux - вопрос в том как при вызове класса Download возвратить результат из onPostExecute в вызывающем классе.  Библиотеку не использую так как не имел опыта скачивания изображений с сервера в память устройства с помощью библиотеки.

Comment: @Pentiux - данная архитектура работает но я хочу контролировать процесс итерации и запускать следующий вызов для `new Download(getActivity() . . .` если в ответ получил true или какое либо int